# Enable user to Zoom In/Out Image in full Screen Mode in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I want to allow user to `Zoom In/Out Image` in `full Screen Mode`. For that, I am opening new Activity for `ImageView` by passing Image Value. So there, User can see Image.
Now, I want to allow user to Zoom Image using Two Finder Trip.
How to do this ?
I don't want Rotation image by Finger Touch, I want only Zoom In/Out.
I want it supportable from api 8.

Answer (score 0):

For Zoom In and Zoom Out you have to add two xml file in your res/anim folder.

here is zoomin.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="3"
    android:toYScale="3" >
</scale>
```

here is zoomout.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" >
</scale>
```

Now you have to set in animation and out animation from java file

```
setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext(), R.anim.right_in));
.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext(), R.anim.left_out));
```

Comment: where to give path of image ?

Comment: Use ViewFlipper and add Imageview in viewflipper.
You can setInAnimation and setOutAnimation in ViewFlipper

Comment: I dont have any idea. Give me example.

Comment: <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/view_flipper_island"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
                </ViewFlipper>

Comment: add Imageview in ViewFlipper

Comment: I have tried it but It is not doing any zoom by finger touch.

Comment: Than there may be problem with your on touch event because above code work complete for me.